# How not select dot and double dots in dired mode

Tags: dired

Linux Mint 20
Emacs 27

package dired, dired+

In folder **Downloads** I has: **one** folder and **two** files.

I want to delete all content of folder **Downloads**

So as result on Dired mode I press **t**.

Here result:

[image]

As you can see marked also dot and double dots.
So as result I can't delete all.
I press **D** and get error:

```
Cannot operate on '.' or '..'
```

[image]

So as result I need MANUAL mark files by press **m** and only then I can delete all content of folder **Downloads**
[image]

So the question is:
Is it possible when press **t** (in dired mode) to not mark dot and double dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Dired+, try this replacement for command `dired-toggle-marks`.  You can then use `C-u` to prevent `.` and `..` from toggling.  (FYI: toggling them is part of a fix for [Emacs bug #48883](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=48883).)

```lisp
(defun dired-toggle-marks (&optional except-dot+dot-dot-p)
  "Toggle marks: marked files become unmarked, and vice versa.
Marks (such as `C' and `D') other than `*' are not affected.
Hidden subdirs are also not affected.

By default, this toggles also `.' and `..' (see Emacs bug #48883).
With a prefix arg it does not toggle `.' and `..'."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((inhibit-read-only  t))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (or (dired-between-files)
            (and except-dot+dot-dot-p
                 (member (dired-get-filename t t) '("." "..")))
            (apply 'subst-char-in-region (point)
                   (1+ (point))
                   (if (eq ?\   (following-char))
                       (list ?\   dired-marker-char)
                     (list dired-marker-char ?\  ))))
        (forward-line 1)))))
```